# 'int' object is not subscriptable arrays

Tags: python, arrays

im trying to get a simple program to work i've slightly updated it but still got problems:

```
numpupils=int(input("how many pupils are there? >> "))
names=[]
marks=[]
results=[]
for pupils in range(numpupils):
    names.append(input("n\nEnter the students name "))
    marks.append(input("Please input the students mark "))
    if marks[numpupils] > 70:
        result.append("A")
    elif marks > 60:
        result.append("b")
    elif marks> 50:
        result.append("C")
    elif marks> 45:
        result.append("D")
    elif marks < 45:
        result.append("Fail")
    print(names, marks, results)


print("\tName\tMark\tResult")
print("\t====\t====\t======")
for index in range(5):
    print(index+1,"\t",names[index],"\t",marks[index],"\t",results[index])
```

and when i run it again i get:
list index out of range

so again if you could help me i would really appreciate it

Comment: @HyperZ can't don't know how, first time using this site

Comment: You should state the desired effect of  the program.

Answer (score 3):

Your variables start off as lists

```
name=[]
mark=[]
result=[]
```

but then you replace their values with integers and strings

```
name=str(input("n\nEnter the students name "))
mark=int(input("Please input the students mark "))

...

result="A"
```

so when you get to the output, none of those variables are lists any more.

Additionally, `input` expects to read a valid Python expression that it can evaluate.

To read a string, use `raw_input`.

Example:

```
>>> input(">")
>23
23
>>> input(">")
>hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined

>>> input(">")
>"hello"
'hello'
>>> hello='world'
>>> input(">")
>hello
'world'

>>> raw_input(">")
>23
'23'
>>> raw_input(">")
>hello
'hello'
```

You want something like this

```
for pupil in range(numpupils):
    name[pupil] = raw_input("n\nEnter the students name ")
    mark[pupil] = int(raw_input("Please input the students mark "))
    # or
    # mark[pupil] = input("Please input the students mark "))

    if mark[pupil] > 70:
        result[pupil] = "A"
    ...
```

Tips: use the plural for naming variables which are collections:

```
names = []
marks = []
results = []
```

And when debugging things like this, a tiny

```
print name, mark, result
```

just before the problem occurs can help you find the issue faster.

Comment: i tried your solution but at the same place just before the print index+1 it now says 'str' object does not support item assignment on line 14 which is   name[pupil] = str(input("n\nEnter the students name "))

Comment: @games4uall You have somehow assigned a string to `name`. Don't do that. Remember that `name` is supposed to be a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined empty lists for name, mark and results, but you then immediately overwrite them with values, rather than appending to the lists.

It should be:

```
for pupils in range(numpupils):
    name.append(input("n\nEnter the students name "))
```

etc.